# Implicit differentiation (csc(x^2) + y^2)^2 = sqrt(x-tan(y))

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Implicit differentiation dy/dx of the following curve:
$$(csc(x^2) + y^2)^2 = \sqrt{x - tan(y)}$$

[This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit%20differentiation&a=*C.implicit%20differentiation-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%28csc%28x%5E2%29%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%5E2%20%3D%20sqrt%28x%20-%20tan%28y%29%29&f=ImplicitDerivative.derivativefunction_%28csc%28x%5E2%29%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%5E2%20%3D%20sqrt%28x%20-%20tan%28y%29%29&f3=x&f=ImplicitDerivative.derivativevariable%5Cu005fx) is how wolfram alpha solves it.

Anyway,
here's my left hand side:
$$2(csc(x^2) + y^2) * (-2x * csc(x^2) * cot(x^2) + 2yy')$$

right hand side
I get:
$$\frac{1}{2} (x - tan(y))^{-1/2} * (1 - y' * sec^2(y))$$

->
$$
(2csc(x^2) + 2y^2) * (-2xcsc(x^2) * cot(x^2) + 2yy') = \frac{1 - y'*sec^2(y)}{ 2 * \sqrt{x - tan(y)}}
$$

okay, so after expanding everything my full equation would look like this:
$$
-4xcsc^2(x^2) * cot(x^2) + 4csc(x^2) * yy' - 4y^2 *x * csc(x^2) * cot(x^2) + 4y^3 y' = \frac{1-y' * sec^2(y))}{2 * (x - tan(y))^{1/2}}$$

am I correct so far?

I then subtract $$
\frac{1 - y'*sec^2(y)}{ 2 * \sqrt{x - tan(y)}}$$
from both sides, and move everything except terms containing y' to the right:
$$
4csc(x^2)yy' + 4y^3y' - \frac{1 - y'*sec^2(y)}{ 2 * \sqrt{x - tan(y)}} = 4xcsc^2(x^2)*cot(x^2) + 4y^2 xcsc(x^2) * cot(x^2)$$

I then multiply both sides by:
$$( 2 * \sqrt{x - tan(y)} )$$

to get rid of the denominator on the left hand side:
$$
( 2 * \sqrt{x - tan(y)} ) * (4csc(x^2)yy' + 4y^3y') - (1 - y'*sec^2(y)) = ( 2 * \sqrt{x - tan(y)} ) * (4xcsc^2(x^2)*cot(x^2) + 4y^2 xcsc(x^2) * cot(x^2))
$$

eventually I get:
$$
y' = \frac{ (8 x y^2 cot(x^2) csc(x^2) \sqrt{x-tan(y)} +8 x cot(x^2) csc^2(x^2) \sqrt{x-tan(y)} +1)}{(8 y csc(x^2) \sqrt{x-tan(y)}+8 y^3 \sqrt{x-tan(y)} +sec^2(y))}
$$

p.s. instead of subtracting the entire quotient:
$$
\frac{1 - y'*sec^2(y)}{ 2 * \sqrt{x - tan(y)}}$$

I was dividing by (1 - y'*sec^2(y)) both sides, that's why I was ending up with y' in the denominator on the left hand side, and I couldn't take out y' on the LHS.

Comment: This involves some really tedious calculations, you can check the answer here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit+differentiation+of+2%28csc%28x%5E2%29%2By%5E2%29%5E2%3D%28x-tan%28y%29%29%5E%5B1%2F2%5D. Also, you can notice that you must have made an error somewhere since if you collect the $y'$ terms on the left, you have $'y*[y(4csc(x^2)+4y^3]/y'*sec^2(y)$, which would not make sense, since you can cancel out all the $y'$s, which is what we want to solve for.

Comment: @H_T in your link there's 2 in front of the whole equation, there shouldn't be. So where did I make an error? I can't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made several mistakes in your "expanding everything" step:

$$-4x\csc^2{(x^2)} \cot{(x^2)} + 4\csc{(x^2)}  yy' - 4xy^2\csc{(x^2)}\cot{(x^2)} + 4y^3 y' = \frac{1-y'\sec^2{y}}{2 (x - \tan{y})^{1/2}}$$

Look at the 3rd, 4th term and the numerator on the right hand side.

And after that, you should move all three terms with $y'$ to the left by adding or subtracting, then factor out $y'$ from all of them. That way you won't have $y'$ both in top and bottom.

First you should separate the numerator on the right hand side:

$$-4x\csc^2{(x^2)} \cot{(x^2)} + 4\csc{(x^2)}  yy' - 4xy^2\csc{(x^2)}\cot{(x^2)} + 4y^3 y' = \frac{1}{2 (x - \tan{y})^{1/2}}-\frac{y'\sec^2{y}}{2 (x - \tan{y})^{1/2}}$$

Then move the terms:

$$4\csc{(x^2)}  yy' + 4y^3 y'+ \frac{\sec^2{y}y'}{2 (x - \tan{y})^{1/2}}=4x\csc^2{(x^2)} \cot{(x^2)}+4xy^2\csc{(x^2)}\cot{(x^2)}+ \frac{1}{2 (x - \tan{y})^{1/2}}$$

$$(4\csc{(x^2)}  y + 4y^3 + \frac{\sec^2{y}}{2 (x - \tan{y})^{1/2}})y'=4x\csc^2{(x^2)} \cot{(x^2)}+4xy^2\csc{(x^2)}\cot{(x^2)}+ \frac{1}{2 (x - \tan{y})^{1/2}}$$

Then divide by the coefficient of $y'$.

Comment: wait, how do you get -2 before 3rd and 4th terms? What do you get in second parenthesis? Here's my LHS: (2csc(x^2) + 2y^2) * (-2xcsc(x^2) * cot(x^2) + 2yy')

Comment: if you take derivative of csc(x^2) you'll get: -2xcot(x^2) csc(x^2)

Comment: Right, somehow I saw the wrong numbers. They should be $4$.

Comment: I don't quite get it, how do you end up with (sec^2 yy′)/(2(x−tany)^(1/2)) on the lhs? shouldn't it be 1- sec^2 yy′ in the numerator? Besides, how do you move it to the left side? If you add it to the left side, shouldn't it get doubled on the right side?

Comment: I edited a little. Hope that helps.